# Unable to launch Java Virtual Machine on Java 11

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, java-11, launch

I am unable to launch a Java Virtual Machine on Java 11 with GC log JVM argument enabled based on the error below:

```
D:\Software\jdk-11.0.1\bin>java -Xlog:gc=debug:file=D:\NEOLMS\LOG\LMS\GC.log
[0.007s][error][logging] Invalid decorator '\NEOLMS\LOG\LMS\GC.log'.
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc=debug:file=D:\NEOLMS\LOG\LMS\GC.log', see error log for details.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

It works perfectly fine when GC log file is specified without path as per below syntax:

```
D:\Software\jdk-11.0.1\bin>java -Xlog:gc=debug:file=GC.log
```